# How to send Laravel Passport Token in URL body not in Header In RESTful API

Tags: php, authentication, url, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am new of learning and work with RESTful API and Laravel and I spend a days searching on how to send Passport token in body request like other params and not in middleware like this

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
        Route::post('getdetails', 'PassportController@getDetails');
    });
```

I found that every tutroial using this way
like this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20180615132648/http://www.yudiz.com:80/laravel-5-4-oauth2-passport-authentation-via-mobile-web-services/)

how can I send it with body like other parms